¿Cómo hacer un contador en sql el cual por empleado solo me deje guardar hasta el numero 15?
Hola a todos espero poder explicarme correctamente.
Tengo un query el en el cual tengo diferentes registros algo así:

Lo que necesito es poder hacer algo en SQL lo cual me permita hacer lo siguiente:
En el caso de Id: 8544 tiene 2 registros los cuales sumados dan 14, en ese caso ambos registros deben de aparecer.
en el caso del 9509 igual, la suma de los 3 registros da 10, entonces deben aparecer.
En el caso del 9883 en ese caso su primer registro ya me da los 15 días, por lo cual el otro registro no debe de aparecer.
y el último caso el 10834 la suma de sus dos registros nos da 18, por lo cual debe de aparecer el primero pero el segundo solo debe de mostrar 4, para que su suma no de mas de 15.
Espero haberme explicado de la mejor manera y alguien tenga alguna idea o solución.
Los dos primero casos no son problema ya que no se juntan más de 15, no importa si tiene 2, 3, 4 etc, registros mientras no sean más de 15 no tengo problema, el problema son aquellos que sumados dan más de 15.
Sin importar los registros que sea todos deben de aparecer.
Muchas gracias. Saludos.

Y tiene que ser un query porque.....

No veo nada conveniente que busques hacer esto usando SQL. Porque no mas bien en el programa que se conecta a tu base de datos, enlistas y agrupas tus resultados y luego operas con ellos de la manera que mas te sirva?

Me parece que puedes usar la sentencia HAVING.
No lo he probado en alguna base de datos pero el query podría quedar de la siguiente manera.
select id_empleado, sum(días) as días group by id_empleado having dias < 15

Igual te dejo alguna documentación de HAVING para que te puedas ayudar
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp
Espero haber podido ayudarte.

Tu fuente de datos carece de un campo o conjunto de campos que dicte un orden particular, por lo tanto al hablar de primer registro, segundo registro, etc., estás ignorando el hecho de que en SQL los conjuntos de datos no tienen un orden por defecto, por lo tanto solo podemos hablar de primer registro, segundo registro, si decimos, ordenados por tal o cual campo o combinación de ellos.
Dicho esto, podemos lograr lo que buscas llevando una sumatoria parcial de días en cada registro. Para ello, podemos valernos de la función de ventana sum(), por ejemplo:
select   id_empleado
       , dias
       , SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by (select null) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sumaDias
  from Tabla

Me va a ir dando la sumatoria de días en cada fila, según el orden arbitrario que resulte de ejecutar esa consulta en un motor determinado.
Repito, lo ideal aquí sería dar un orden particular en la cláusula over order by y me estoy valiendo de un truco para saltarnos esa cláusula y utilizar el orden que ya traiga el conjunto de datos.
Hago énfasis en que ese orden debe considerarse aleatorio y nada obliga al motor a mantenerlo en todas las ejecuciones. Aunque en SQL server no es común que varíe entre una ejecución y otra, puede variar entre una instalación y otra, entre un motor y otro y entre una base de datos y otra.
Dicho esto, podemos obtener el resultado filtrando por esta nueva pseudo-columna, valiéndonos de un CTE, por ejemplo:
; with 
calculo as (
select id_empleado, dias, SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by (select null) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sumaDias
  from Tabla
)
select id_empleado, dias
  from calculo
 where sumaDias <= 15

Aplicado sobre los datos de tu ejemplo, en una ejecución, nos devuelve:
id_empleado dias
----------- -----------
6097        2
8544        7
8544        7
9509        1
9509        7
9509        2
9767        15
9883        15
10834       7

(9 rows affected)

Agregando una supuesta columna id_dias sobre la cual ordeno:
; with
calculo as (
select id_dias, id_empleado, dias, SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by id_dias rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sumaDias
  from Tabla
)
select id_dias, id_empleado, dias
  from calculo
 where sumaDias <= 15
 order by id_dias;

Nos va a devolver siempre este resultado:
id_dias     id_empleado dias
----------- ----------- -----------
1           6097        2
2           8544        7
3           8544        7
4           9509        1
5           9509        7
6           9509        2
7           9767        15
8           9883        15
10          10834       11

(9 rows affected)

Edición
Había obviado las filas para completar 15 días, como el caso del empleado con id 10834 mencionado en la pregunta. Continuaré con el desarrollo, a partir de aquí, asumiendo la existencia de esta columna.
Para construir la solución final, necesitamos no solo saber la suma de días hasta este registro, lo que nos permite excluir los registros que dan más de 15 días como suma, sino que, en los casos donde hace falta, necesitamos también el registro donde se superan los 15 días, siempre los días totales hasta el anterior sean menores de 15 días, para dar un valor parcial que sume en total los 15 días, como es el caso del empleado 10834 del ejemplo.
Podemos obtener la suma de días del registro anterior siempre con la función sum(), en este caso, aplicándola no hasta este registro sino hasta el anterior, así:
SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by id_dias rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding

Dado que esto nos va a devolver null para la primera filas de cada partición por empleado, nos valemos de coalesce() para reflejar 0 comor resultado.
Y entonces, nuestro filtro se convertiría en:
 where sumaDiasAnterior < 15

Finalmente, para calcular el valor de días que corresponde a la última fila usamos la fórmula:
15 - sumaDiasAnterior

Poniendo todo junto:
; with
calculo as (
select   id_dias
       , id_empleado
       , dias
       , SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by id_dias rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sumaDias
       , coalesce(SUM(dias) over (partition by id_empleado order by id_dias rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) sumaDiasAnterior
  from Tabla
)
select   id_dias
       , id_empleado
       , case
           when sumaDias <= 15 then dias
           else 15 - sumaDiasAnterior
         end dias
  from calculo
 where sumaDiasAnterior < 15
 order by id_dias;

Nos devuelve:
id_dias     id_empleado dias
----------- ----------- -----------
1           6097        2
2           8544        7
3           8544        7
4           9509        1
5           9509        7
6           9509        2
7           9767        15
8           9883        15
10          10834       11
11          10834       4

(10 rows affected)

dbfiddle

Muchas gracias en ese caso me ayuda con el caso del ID 9883 el cual con un solo registro se juntan los 15 y el otro ya no aparece, pero me faltaria el caso del 10834 que como me muestras en tu resultado final, quita el segundo registro el de 7 dias, lo correcto es que aparezca pero solo mostrando los 4 dias que restan para completar los 15

Tienes razón, obvie ese caso, edité la respuesta.

calculo as (
select   id_dias*
, id_empleado*
, dias*
, SUM(dias*) over (partition by id_empleado order by id_dias rows* between* unbounded preceding and current row) sumaDias
, coalesce(SUM*(dias*) over (partition* by id_empleado order by id_dias rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) sumaDiasAnterior
from Tabla
)
select   id_dias*
, id_empleado*
, case
when sumaDias* <= 15 then dias*
else 15 - sumaDiasAnterior*
end dias
from calculo*
where sumaDiasAnterior* < 15
order by id_dias*;

Estimado @jachguate, es justamente lo que necesito, pero estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutarlo, ya que tomando el codigo que hizo usted, en la ultima parte, me manda error, en todas las palabras que tienen un * al final.
Ojala pudiera ayudarme un poco mas.

¿Leíste mi respuesta? ¿O solo estás copiando y pegando el código?

Si la leíste, estoy seguro que puedes adaptar el código a tu esquema.
